# How to distribute CPU load among Kubernetes nodes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a kubernetes cluster in GCP with several nodes. Now I'm trying to install monitoring agent in all of them but problem is that two of them have too much CPU load, but on the other hand, the rest have low CPU load.. How can I distribute this load among them?

```
  Resource                   Requests     Limits
  --------                   --------     ------
  cpu                        413m (21%)   0 (0%)
  memory                     266Mi (4%)   550Mi (9%)
--
  Resource                   Requests     Limits
  --------                   --------     ------
  cpu                        513m (26%)   0 (0%)
  memory                     266Mi (4%)   550Mi (9%)
--
  Resource                   Requests     Limits
  --------                   --------     ------
  cpu                        923m (98%)   145m (15%)
  memory                     501Mi (18%)  1135Mi (43%)
--
  Resource                   Requests     Limits
  --------                   --------     ------
  cpu                        913m (97%)   0 (0%)
  memory                     266Mi (10%)  550Mi (20%)
--
  Resource                   Requests     Limits
  --------                   --------     ------
  cpu                        903m (96%)   10m (1%)
  memory                     406Mi (15%)  780Mi (29%)
```

I have not defined any affinity Rule so I don't understand how to k8s make this distribution.. I have thought also increase the machine types but I dont know if it is the best option.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the `kube-scheduler` automatically tries to distribute the load among the available `worker nodes`. Besides the `nodeAffinity` there are several more configurations which force the scheduling of a Pod to a specific node.

1. `nodeSelector`
2. `taints` and `tolerations`

In your case I would recommend to check which pods are assigned on which node. You can get the information via the following command:

```yaml
kubectl get pods -A -o wide
```

In the most Kubernetes configurations the master nodes are per default marked with the taint: `node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule`. This means that besides the pods of the Kubernetes Control Plane no further workloads can be scheduled on your master nodes.
For further investigation more information of your workloads and on which nodes they are running, would be required.